# Wordpress header reverts back to defaul after theme options value changed in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, header-files

I will try to explain this the best way I can. I am working with a theme that has the header text inside of a row in wp_options table. I wanted to change the open hours from "Mon - Sat" to "Tues - Sat" so I selected to edit the row and looked for that section, changed it and submitted the data. After changing that I went back to the home page and refreshed. The header disappeared and changed to the original blog post header. The default version.

I can't seem to get it back. I went into the DB and exported the full DB before I started making these changes so I have a copy of the row before my edit. I copied just the "option_value" section and went back to the DB and pasted the original values - before my changes.

That didn't work. I looked at the multiple versions of headers in the theme and made the changes to the option_value row to test a different header. It didn't work.

Everything above the menu reverted back to the original default version.

Why would it not pull the data in the DB like logo, hours of operation and address if all I did was change a piece of the value?

What can I do to make the version I created appear again?

Maybe anything off the top of your head that I can test?

Thank you for your help, below is the code to what I exported for that rows option_value

```
'a:209:{s:13:"body_paddings";s:2:"no";s:10:"body_style";s:4:"wide";s:10:"theme_skin";s:4:"less";s:11:"body_scheme";s:8:"original";s:11:"body_filled";s:3:"yes";s:9:"bg_custom";s:2:"no";s:8:"bg_color";s:7:"#ffffff";s:10:"bg_pattern";s:0:"";s:17:"bg_pattern_custom";s:0:"";s:8:"bg_image";s:0:"";s:15:"bg_image_custom";s:0:"";s:24:"bg_image_custom_position";s:8:"left_top";s:13:"bg_image_load";s:5:"boxed";s:13:"show_video_bg";s:2:"no";s:21:"video_bg_youtube_code";s:0:"";s:12:"video_bg_url";s:0:"";s:16:"video_bg_overlay";s:2:"no";s:15:"top_panel_style";s:8:"header_2";s:15:"top_panel_image";s:0:"";s:18:"top_panel_position";s:5:"above";s:16:"top_panel_scheme";s:8:"original";s:18:"pushy_panel_scheme";s:4:"dark";s:15:"show_page_title";s:3:"yes";s:16:"show_breadcrumbs";s:3:"yes";s:21:"breadcrumbs_max_level";s:1:"0";s:9:"menu_main";s:7:"default";s:15:"menu_attachment";s:5:"fixed";s:11:"menu_slider";s:3:"yes";s:17:"menu_animation_in";s:6:"fadeIn";s:18:"menu_animation_out";s:11:"fadeOutDown";s:11:"menu_mobile";s:4:"1023";s:10:"menu_width";s:0:"";s:18:"show_top_panel_top";s:2:"no";s:9:"menu_user";s:7:"default";s:14:"show_languages";s:3:"yes";s:10:"show_login";s:3:"yes";s:14:"show_bookmarks";s:3:"yes";s:12:"show_socials";s:3:"yes";s:8:"menu_toc";s:5:"float";s:13:"menu_toc_home";s:3:"yes";s:12:"menu_toc_top";s:3:"yes";s:7:"favicon";s:90:"http://www.cubicitconsulting.com/testbed/macatangay/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/favicon.png";s:4:"logo";s:119:"http://www.cubicitconsulting.com/testbed/macatangay/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/New-Macatangay-Dentistry-Logo-Edited.png";s:11:"logo_retina";s:119:"http://www.cubicitconsulting.com/testbed/macatangay/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/New-Macatangay-Dentistry-Logo-Edited.png";s:10:"logo_fixed";s:119:"http://www.cubicitconsulting.com/testbed/macatangay/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/New-Macatangay-Dentistry-Logo-Edited.png";s:9:"logo_text";s:0:"";s:11:"logo_height";s:0:"";s:11:"logo_offset";s:0:"";s:11:"show_slider";s:2:"no";s:14:"slider_display";s:8:"fullwide";s:13:"slider_height";s:0:"";s:13:"slider_engine";s:6:"swiper";s:12:"slider_alias";s:0:"";s:15:"slider_category";s:0:"";s:12:"slider_posts";s:1:"5";s:14:"slider_orderby";s:4:"date";s:12:"slider_order";s:4:"desc";s:15:"slider_interval";s:4:"7000";s:17:"slider_pagination";s:2:"no";s:14:"slider_infobox";s:5:"slide";s:20:"slider_info_category";s:3:"yes";s:19:"slider_info_reviews";s:3:"yes";s:24:"slider_info_descriptions";s:0:"";s:15:"custom_sidebars";a:1:{i:0;s:11:"FAQ sidebar";}s:17:"show_sidebar_main";s:5:"right";s:19:"sidebar_main_scheme";s:8:"original";s:12:"sidebar_main";s:12:"sidebar_main";s:18:"show_sidebar_outer";s:0:"";s:20:"sidebar_outer_scheme";s:8:"original";s:23:"sidebar_outer_show_logo";s:2:"no";s:26:"sidebar_outer_show_socials";s:2:"no";s:23:"sidebar_outer_show_menu";s:2:"no";s:9:"menu_side";s:0:"";s:26:"sidebar_outer_show_widgets";s:2:"no";s:13:"sidebar_outer";s:12:"sidebar_main";s:19:"show_sidebar_footer";s:3:"yes";s:21:"sidebar_footer_scheme";s:4:"dark";s:14:"sidebar_footer";s:14:"sidebar_footer";s:22:"sidebar_footer_columns";s:1:"3";s:27:"show_testimonials_in_footer";s:2:"no";s:19:"testimonials_scheme";s:8:"original";s:18:"testimonials_count";s:1:"3";s:22:"show_twitter_in_footer";s:2:"no";s:14:"twitter_scheme";s:8:"original";s:13:"twitter_count";s:1:"3";s:14:"show_googlemap";s:2:"no";s:16:"googlemap_height";s:3:"400";s:17:"googlemap_address";s:51:"890 Eastlake Parkway Ste. 201 Chula Vista, CA 91914";s:16:"googlemap_latlng";s:0:"";s:15:"googlemap_title";s:24:"Dr. Macatangay Dentistry";s:21:"googlemap_description";s:0:"";s:14:"googlemap_zoom";s:2:"16";s:15:"googlemap_style";s:11:"ultra_light";s:16:"googlemap_marker";s:0:"";s:23:"show_contacts_in_footer";s:2:"no";s:15:"contacts_scheme";s:8:"original";s:11:"logo_footer";s:0:"";s:18:"logo_footer_retina";s:0:"";s:18:"logo_footer_height";s:2:"30";s:24:"show_copyright_in_footer";s:7:"socials";s:16:"copyright_scheme";s:8:"original";s:11:"menu_footer";s:7:"default";s:16:"footer_copyright";s:126:"Cecile C. Macatangay, DMD © All Rights Reserved. Developed by <a href="http://cubicitconsulting.com/">Cubic IT Consulting</a>";s:21:"show_theme_customizer";s:2:"no";s:15:"customizer_demo";s:1:"0";s:13:"css_animation";s:3:"yes";s:19:"animation_on_mobile";s:3:"yes";s:26:"remember_visitors_settings";s:2:"no";s:18:"responsive_layouts";s:3:"yes";s:14:"page_preloader";s:0:"";s:12:"fonts_subset";s:15:"latin,latin-ext";s:15:"custom_css_html";s:3:"yes";s:8:"gtm_code";s:0:"";s:9:"gtm_code2";s:0:"";s:11:"custom_code";s:0:"";s:10:"custom_css";s:31:".mTopNeg{\r\nmargin-top:-65px;\r\n}";s:10:"blog_style";s:7:"excerpt";s:11:"hover_style";s:19:"square effect_shift";s:9:"hover_dir";s:13:"left_to_right";s:13:"article_style";s:7:"stretch";s:18:"dedicated_location";s:7:"default";s:12:"show_filters";s:4:"hide";s:9:"blog_sort";s:4:"date";s:10:"blog_order";s:4:"desc";s:14:"posts_per_page";s:1:"8";s:22:"post_excerpt_maxlength";s:3:"250";s:30:"post_excerpt_maxlength_masonry";s:3:"150";s:12:"single_style";s:15:"single-standard";s:4:"icon";s:0:"";s:16:"alter_thumb_size";s:3:"1_1";s:19:"show_featured_image";s:3:"yes";s:15:"show_post_title";s:3:"yes";s:25:"show_post_title_on_quotes";s:2:"no";s:14:"show_post_info";s:3:"yes";s:25:"show_text_before_readmore";s:3:"yes";s:16:"show_post_author";s:3:"yes";s:14:"show_post_tags";s:3:"yes";s:17:"show_post_related";s:3:"yes";s:18:"post_related_count";s:1:"2";s:20:"post_related_columns";s:1:"2";s:17:"post_related_sort";s:4:"date";s:18:"post_related_order";s:4:"desc";s:18:"show_post_comments";s:3:"yes";s:12:"exclude_cats";s:8:"34,32,26";s:15:"blog_pagination";s:5:"pages";s:13:"blog_counters";s:20:"views,likes,comments";s:14:"close_category";s:8:"parental";s:15:"show_date_after";s:2:"30";s:12:"show_reviews";s:2:"no";s:17:"reviews_max_level";s:1:"5";s:13:"reviews_style";s:5:"stars";s:24:"reviews_criterias_levels";s:26:"bad,poor,normal,good,great";s:13:"reviews_first";s:6:"author";s:14:"reviews_second";s:4:"show";s:16:"reviews_can_vote";s:3:"all";s:17:"reviews_criterias";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"bad";i:1;s:4:"good";i:2;s:4:"nice";}s:13:"reviews_marks";N;s:12:"retina_ready";s:1:"1";s:14:"images_quality";s:2:"80";s:18:"substitute_gallery";s:2:"no";s:21:"gallery_instead_image";s:3:"yes";s:18:"gallery_max_slides";s:1:"5";s:12:"popup_engine";s:8:"magnific";s:16:"substitute_audio";s:3:"yes";s:16:"substitute_video";s:3:"yes";s:16:"use_mediaelement";s:3:"yes";s:12:"social_icons";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:12:"icon-twitter";}i:1;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:10:"icon-gplus";}i:2;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:13:"icon-facebook";}i:3;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:9:"icon-digg";}}s:10:"show_share";s:4:"hide";s:19:"show_share_counters";s:2:"no";s:13:"share_caption";s:8:"Share It";s:13:"share_buttons";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:13:"icon-facebook";}i:1;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:9:"icon-digg";}i:2;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:12:"icon-twitter";}i:3;a:2:{s:3:"url";s:1:"#";s:4:"icon";s:10:"icon-gplus";}}s:16:"twitter_username";s:0:"";s:20:"twitter_consumer_key";s:0:"";s:23:"twitter_consumer_secret";s:0:"";s:17:"twitter_token_key";s:0:"";s:20:"twitter_token_secret";s:0:"";s:12:"contact_info";s:51:"890 Eastlake Parkway Ste. 201 Chula Vista, CA 91914";s:18:"contact_open_hours";s:64:"Mon - Sat: <strong>Call for Appointment</strong> Sun-Mon: Closed";s:13:"contact_email";s:0:"";s:17:"contact_address_1";s:29:"890 Eastlake Parkway Ste. 201";s:17:"contact_address_2";s:21:"Chula Vista, CA 91914";s:13:"contact_phone";s:39:"Free Call <strong>619-421-2828</strong>";s:11:"contact_fax";s:0:"";s:26:"message_maxlength_contacts";s:4:"1000";s:26:"message_maxlength_comments";s:4:"1000";s:13:"mail_function";s:7:"wp_mail";s:11:"show_search";s:3:"yes";s:15:"use_ajax_search";s:3:"yes";s:22:"ajax_search_min_length";s:1:"4";s:17:"ajax_search_delay";s:3:"500";s:17:"ajax_search_types";s:0:"";s:23:"ajax_search_posts_count";s:1:"5";s:23:"ajax_search_posts_image";s:3:"yes";s:22:"ajax_search_posts_date";s:3:"yes";s:24:"ajax_search_posts_author";s:3:"yes";s:26:"ajax_search_posts_counters";s:3:"yes";s:29:"notify_about_new_registration";s:2:"no";s:22:"use_ajax_views_counter";s:3:"yes";s:12:"allow_editor";s:2:"no";s:17:"admin_add_filters";s:3:"yes";s:25:"show_overriden_taxonomies";s:3:"yes";s:20:"show_overriden_posts";s:3:"yes";s:16:"admin_dummy_data";s:3:"yes";s:19:"admin_dummy_timeout";s:3:"120";s:13:"admin_emailer";s:2:"no";s:17:"admin_po_composer";s:2:"no";s:10:"debug_mode";s:2:"no";s:10:"api_google";s:0:"";s:14:"use_menu_cache";s:2:"no";}'
```

All I changed was the hour info and tried changing the header file name after it broke down. Submitted the file but none brought my header back. What could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the length of the string in serialized data without changing the value showing the length of the string.

For example, if your data is this:

a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}

and you changed it to:

a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget1";i:1;}

it would fail since you changed the string from 12 characters to 13 characters without changing the length definition.  To change it correctly, you would do this:

a:1:{s:13:"_multiwidget1";i:1;}

It is generally not recommended to change serialized data by hand, but if you do, you need to understand the serialization so that you can fix it to the changes you make.